# Deserialize JSON Strings Directly into Models?

Tags: ruby, json, activerecord, garbage-collection

I have ruby models which are populated from the responses of API calls in the following way:

1. `JSON.parse` converts the response to a `Hash`
2. the `Hash` is passed into the `initialize` method of a class
3. the `initialize` method converts camelCase hash keys and assigns underscore_case instance variables

This works fine, but some of these response objects are large.  Others are arrays of large objects.

Profiling shows that this process consumes a lot of memory -- makes sense, I create hashes in order to create objects, and I'm sure the camelCase to underscore_case conversion is expensive -- so what libraries or techniques have you come across which solve this problem?

---

(update) Here is an oversimplified example:

JSON response from a third party API (unlikely to change):

```
"{\"abcDef\": 123, \"ghiJkl\": 456, \"mnoPqr\": 789}"
```

Class definition (unlikely to change):

```
class Data
  attr_accessor :abc_def, :ghi_jkl, :mno_pqr

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |key, val|
      send "#{key.underscore}=".to_sym, val
    end
  end
end
```

Creating an object:

```
Data.new JSON.parse(api.get)
```

Comment: I think a little code example would help. It might also work with more of your conversion code as a question on codereview.stackexchange, because your problem is about efficiency and design. Please also make clear whether altering the behaviour of the API you are calling is in scope to change. Can you alter the API?

Comment: Another thing worth clarifying: Does your client code need to deal with arbitrary keys in the API response? In which case the whole conversion routine is suspect (i.e. you are better off just working with the hash). Or is the data well-described and stable? In which case you do have better (as in faster and more memory-efficient) options than auto-conversion, based on coding in some of the knowledge of how the data objects are structured.

Comment: Thanks for the comments Neil, I had no idea that the codereview subdomain existed.  I will move this over there shortly.

Comment: @NeilSlater http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69855/deserialize-json-strings-directly-into-models